# How to use Qt/C++ to create/read/write files and store settings local with the program

Tags: c++, database, qt, user-interface, settings

I'm an unfortunate beginner at C++ and using the Qt GUI designer program seemed perfect for my needs, except I'm having problems trying to write out the code necessary for this.  I could use the QSettings string to store local settings on the hard drive, but I personally hate it when programs do the %HOME_LOCAL%\APPS_SETTINGS bull that some do.  I need to save a text file for both settings and a local\host database, within the program directory, to remember strings to read from later.

What is the line of code I need to make use of a local host text database or is there a better option?  And how can I store that with the local program inside its directory?

Comment: If an admin installs an application, then a non-admin user cannot use the application properly.

Comment: If you store the information next to the application you will fall foul of permission failure on most operating systems. If you you plan on deploying this to more than just your own personal use you'll need to think about keeping your application separate from the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `QSettings` with any file, with [constructor `QSettings::QSettings ( const QString & fileName, Format format, QObject * parent = 0 )`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#QSettings-4).

To get the program directory, you can use [`QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath).

So, answer to your question, statement to put after creation of QApplication instance:

```
QSettings *settings = new QSettings(
     QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/settings.ini",
     QSettings::IniFormat,
     qApp);
```

But, as noted in the comments under question, if you're making your program for general distribution, you should use the OS default. Examine all the constructors of [`QSettings`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#QSettings) to see what it can do. User does not often have write permission in the application directory. Note that you can also store settings to Windows registry with [QSettings::NativeFormat](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#Format-enum).

Comment: Thanks.  I'm starting to quickly figure out this is going to be a very complex project quickly..